# Grails: how to stop application started with "run-app prod" without "kill"

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy

Is there such a possibility?

Would love Tomcast to persist session data on shutdown.

Comment: Why not just build the prod WAR (`grails prod war`) and deploy to Tomcat the standard way?

Answer (score 6):

Create a file called `.kill-run-app` in the root directory of the project (use touch in Linux/OSX or just create an empty file) and it will cleanly shut down. I'm not sure if sessions are serialized though.

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure you don't run your application in production using `grails run-app`. It is only intended for development. 
Instead, you should create a war file `grails war` and deploy it in your web container (tomcat). Production is the default environment used when creating a war file.
You can also use `grails run-war` to test that application works as expected from the packaged WAR file but again, this is not suitable for production.

Comment: Could you please also briefly say why exactly `grails run-war` is not suitable for production?

Answer (score 2):

If you run `kill -TERM` you send the process a signal to do a clean shut down. I would have thought Tomcat would persist session data before doing so.